# How do I fix the "unable to find 'distinguised_name' in config problems making Certificate Request" error using OpenSSL?

Tags: api, openssl

I have no idea what this error is or how to fix it. I am just following these instructions to connect to a VISA API (https://developer.visa.com/pages/working-with-visa-apis/two-way-ssl). I am on the "Configuring Two-Way SSL Keystore Using Your Own CSR" section of instructions #1.

I did try to follow the VISA instructions once, but got errors and restarted from the beginning so that may contribute to the problem. I might already have a CSR.

I have OpenSSL 1.1.1d 10 Sep 2019
platform: VC-WIN64A

Environment variable SSL not defined
Environment variable OPENSSL not defined

I tried running this command:  req -new -keyout privateKey.pem -out certreq.csr

It then made me enter a PEM pass phrase. I dont know if this makes a difference, but I did the same command before and it worked.

OpenSSL Version
[image]

OpenSSL Error
[image]

Comment: Does it really say 'distinguised_name' and not the correctly-spelled 'distinguished_name'? What kind of system are you on (Windows, MacOS, Linux -- which, etc) and where did you get your OpenSSL (from the OS vendor/repo or someone else -- who) and did you or anyone subsequently modify or patch it? What is the output of `openssl version -a` (edit into your Q)? Do you have any envvars set whose names begin with OPENSSL or SSL? On Unix do `env |grep -e ^SSL -e ^OPENSSL`, on Windows do `set SSL & set OPENSSL`.

Comment: Ok, added more info.

Comment: `version -a` should output much more info than that, including a line for OPENSSLDIR. With no envvars set to override and no option specified, you are (implicitly) using `openssl.cfg` in that directory for config. Check modtime on that file to see if it was modified recently, and creationtime also if you can. From it post at least the 'req' section, which is from the line `[ req ]` up to the next line like `[ anything ]`. The config file usually isn't very big so post all if you like.

Comment: So I was following instructions on how to create a key/certificate file using OpenSSL. I think I got stuck when I had to test connectivity because you needed a keystore username and password. I didn't know my password so I started from the beginning. I have no idea what happened, but my files are back and now I have shown connectivity by connecting to SoapUI helloworld sample. I have no idea what just happened, but thanks for your help!